# Python in VBA function : xlwings

Tags: python-3.x, excel, vba, xlwings

I am using the xlwings library to run python in VBA Sub. Inside the python module I  import the CLR library to call C# classes. When I run the code in Excel it returns the following:

---

### Error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "t:\development\retailPythonModule.py", line 11, in <module>
    import xlwings as xw
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\__init__.py", line 23, in <module>
    from . import _xlwindows as xlplatform
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 25, in <module>
    from comtypes import IUnknown
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 165, in <module>
    CoInitializeEx()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\comtypes\__init__.py", line 156, in CoInitializeEx
    _ole32.CoInitializeEx(None, flags)
  File "_ctypes/callproc.c", line 918, in GetResult
OSError: [WinError -2147417850] Cannot change thread mode after it is set

Press Ctrl+C to copy this message to the clipboard.

OK
```

This code works fine in Jupiter notebook, it's only when I try to run it through excel.

Please help, I am still very new in this.

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix the problem. I was importing clr before xlwings, so by importing xlwings first solved the problem.